# When does a web service load a external dll that it uses?

Tags: c#, web-services, pinvoke

I have a web service that is using an external dll via pinvoke. My question is, when is the external dll loaded - when the web service starts or only when the service contract that invokes it is called?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unmanaged DLL is loaded when it is first used.

This is the same behavior as with managed assemblies your program uses.